# Can't get valid filepaths read from a text file to word. Double quotes don't work. (Run-time error '5152' with InlineShapes)

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word

I need to replace 108 images in word. I wrote VBA code so that for each inline image read in the document, the image will be replace by a new image. The new image is specified by a array that has filepaths in each element. The array comes from a text file.

For some reason, my code won't work if I have my variable, strPath as

```
strPath = dataArray(i)
```

or

```
strPath = Chr(34) & dataArray(i) & Chr(34)
```

What does work is if I type in

```
dataArray(0) = "C:\IMGS\G.2.1\NZ_DWH_v_SIMAP_AR1_biovalbox1_1100-1400m_Apr20-May26.png"
```

The path in the textfile is 
`C:\IMGS\G.2.1\NZ_DWH_v_SIMAP_AR1_biovalbox1_1100-1400m_Apr20-May26.png`

I have 108 lines in the textfile, each for the image that needs to be replaced.
I have displayed the path in a message box and it looks like the above, so I am not sure why I can't get file paths from an array. Can someone help me?

```
    '1-loop thru all figs
    '2-bring up box to select figure
    '3-add figure
    Dim intChoice As Integer
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim objPic As InlineShape
    Dim intCount As Integer

    'import text
    Dim dataArray() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim g As Integer
    strFileName = "C:\Users\cturner\Desktop\filesimgs_order.txt"
    Open strFileName For Input As #1
    dataArray = Split(Input$(LOF(1), #1), vbLf)
    Close #1

    g = 0
    intCount = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
    'loop through inline shapes
    For i = 0 To intCount
        strPath = Chr(34) & dataArray(i) & Chr(34)
        MsgBox (TypeName(strPath))
        g = g + 1
        'check if valid filepath
        'Debug.Print FileExists(strPath)
        MsgBox strPath
        'check if the current shape is an picture
        If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(g).Type = wdInlineShapePicture Then
            Set objPic = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(g)
            objPic.Select
            'insert the image
            Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= strPath, _
                LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Usually, a text file has carriage returns and line feeds, so maybe your string variables still have the vbCR character in them? Perhaps you could loop through your variable and test the ASCII value of each character?

Comment: @ChipsLetten , you wonderful person you, I think I DO have vbCr I didn't think about looking for that! I'm going to try replacing it with "" to see what happens. For those who want to know how I check for it, I split the array by vbCr. If there is no character match, the LBound(splitarray) and UBound(splitarray) should equal to zero. Otherwise you'd get something like UBound=1

Comment: @ChipsLetten , that was the problem. I don't know how to submit a comment as a solution, so I just updated my code with the fix. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Suprise Suprise, I forgot to trim the carriage return vbCr. After I got that out, code works fine and I am able to replace my buttload of images.

Part 1. I checked my string if it has carriage return. Main problem is that I didn't clean my string, and thus putting it into a function made vba throw the error message (no bueno). If you have it, UBound should = 1

```
For i = 0 To 2
strPath = dataArray(i)
checkcr = Split(strPath, vbCr)
firstIndex = LBound(checkcr)
lastIndex = UBound(checkcr)

MsgBox (firstIndex)
MsgBox (lastIndex)
MsgBox checkcr(lastIndex)
newstrPath = Replace(strPath, vbCr, "")
MsgBox newstrPath
Next i
```

Part 2. Corrected Code + bonus. Bouns: some code to check if the file exists (from [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?349990-Classic-VB-How-can-I-check-if-a-file-exists) )

fix:

```
newstrPath = Replace(strPath, vbCr, "")
```

Updated Code:

```
Sub replacefigs()
' replacefigs Macro
' To replace old figures with new figures (updated disclosure)
'0-get full file paths from textfile
'1-loop thru all figs
'2-bring up box to select figure
'3-add figure

Dim intChoice As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim objPic As InlineShape
Dim intCount As Integer


'import text
Dim dataArray() As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim g As Integer

strFileName = "C:\Users\cturner\Desktop\filesimgs_order.txt"
Open strFileName For Input As #1
dataArray = Split(Input$(LOF(1), #1), vbLf)
Close #1

g = 0

intCount = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Count
'loop through inline shapes
For i = 0 To intCount

strPath = dataArray(i)
'Get rid of carriage returns
newstrPath = Replace(strPath, vbCr, "")

g = g + 1

'to check if file exists
'Debug.Print FileExists(newstrPath)

    'check if the current shape is an picture
    If ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(g).Type = _
        wdInlineShapePicture Then

        Set objPic = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(g)
        objPic.Select
    'insert the image
        Selection.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
         newstrPath, LinkToFile:=False, _
        SaveWithDocument:=True

    End If
Next i

End Sub
```